# Image cropping using jquery plugin Image Cropper

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

I am using a jquery plugin called [ImageCropper](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/03/image-cropper-jquery-image-cropping-plugin/). And this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfQyu/8/) to it.

When I change the `y2` coordinate of the image it doesnt change in the preview.What must be going wrong?Rest of the coordinates work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your fiddle and the [demo page](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?BEAlLLl9) (set it to "Free Ratio") and it behaves the same in both, its a bug of the plugin itself.

If you set an aspectRatio it works properly but otherwise it doesn't. Apparently the event listener for dragging down isn't working, so if you set the aspectRatio the listeners for the sides must be triggering the update for the preview.

Try to notify the author of the plugin with an issue or bug so he/she can fix it.

Otherwise, I would recomend Guillotine that's the plugin I use or Jcrop that's the one I used before that, depending on your needs:

- [Guillotine](http://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine): Crop, zoom, rotate, responsive and touch support (really lightweight).
- [Jcrop](http://www.deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html): Cropping with free ratio.